How to pass multiple options stored in a variable to command in bash?
I'm trying to pass multiple options to FFMPEG command but it is failing with unrecognized option '-nostdin -hide_banner -nostats -loglevel error'. How do I fix it by passing the options as a variable?
FFMPEG_ARGS="-nostdin -hide_banner -nostats -loglevel error"
ffmpeg "$FFMPEG_ARGS" -y -i "$SOURCE" "$OUTPUT"


You're using Bash, store them in an array.

I tried: FFMPEG_COMMON=( -nostdin,-hide_banner,-nostats,-loglevel error ) ffmpeg "${FFMPEG_COMMON[@]}" but it doesn't seem to work

Use whitespace, not commas to separate items in a Bash array.

This question is similar to: How can I store a list of arguments in a variable in bash?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] this question to make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
